# В Wordpress не работает пагинация

Tags: wordpress, пагинация

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я делаю запрос по типу

```
$events = new WP_Query(['post_type' => EVENT_POST_TYPE, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged'=> get_query_var( 'page' ),]); ?>
```

После чего пагинацию делаю

```
echo paginate_links( [
    'base'    => user_trailingslashit( wp_normalize_path( get_permalink() .'/%#%/' ) ),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) ),
    'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
] );
```

Проблема в том, что 1 страница отображается, а page/2/ и т.д. 404 кидает.
Я так понимаю проблема в Custom Structure /news/%postname%/. Похоже с гет параметрами лажа. Кто знает как это можно исправить подскажите. Есть конечно костыль, по типу просто создавать другую ссылку такого типа https://funnelatwork.com/events/?pg=1 и проверяй в шаблоне гет параметр `pg` `$_GET['pg']`, но это решение так себе.

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/